# bxSlider Doesn't work Properly on Dynamic content

Tags: bxslider

I am using bxslider. but its doesn't work properly

html

```
<ul class="bxslider" id="opList">

</ul>
```

js

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         autoControls: true,
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 3,
          slideWidth: '100%',
          slideMargin: 10,
     });


    for(var i=0; i<=5;i++)
    {
        var opLi = $('<li><img src="img/surgeries.png"></li>'); 
        $('#opList').append(opLi);  
    }
```

It works correctly when put the list static.

But it doesn't work when i give li dynamically

Answer (score 2):

This might fix the issue

```html
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal'
});

$('#reload-slider').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.bxslider').append('<li><img src="/images/730_200/trees.jpg"></li>');
  slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the bxslider code below your other code. This way your dynamic list will be populated before bxslider loads.